# I can't access windows 10 homepage

Tags: windows-10

How do I access my charter.net homepage with the new windows 10? There's no IE icon on task bar like my old windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

- Find Internet Explorer in the Start menu

or

- Use Edge, which is the new default browser in Windows 10:

  [image: Edge icon on the taskbar]

  Edge can also be found in the Start menu, just like any other program. Use the *All apps* button or just start typing program name while Start menu is open.

  [image: All apps button]